# How do I grab the selected radiobox value from a particular form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some generated HTML along the lines of this.

```html
<form id="form_56">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="0">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="3">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="4">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="5">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="6">
</form>
```

The form id can be anything, but I want to take a form ID and return the selected value from 0 to 6.

I tried following the questions here, but they didn't seem to translate easily to a specific form.

`$('#form_56:radio[name=option]:checked').val();`

I'm able to use the selector to grab the proper form, but everything I've attempted to get the selected value has returned undefined.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change the colon to a space or " > ".

Second you need to change radio to input.

```
$('#form_56 input[name=option]:checked').val();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_56">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="0">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="2">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="3">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="4">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="5">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="6">
</form>

<a href="javascript:console.log($('#form_56 input[name=option]:checked').val());">
  <button>Test</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#form_56 input:radio[name='option']").val()
```

You need an event for listening when it changes
see example

```
$(function() {

  $("#form_56 input:radio[name='option']").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    alert(val);
  });


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rodrigo/cp8rd7h0/

Comment: I'm tallying these all up at the end; An event would be quite uncalled for.

Answer (score 1):

For any form:

```
$('form>input[type="radio"]:checked').val()
```

With id:

```
$('#form_56>input[type="radio"]:checked').val()
```

It will return selected value or undefined, if no value selected.
Good luck!

```js
function getSelectedValue()
{
  return $('form>input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
}
$(function() {
  $('button').on(
    'click', 
    function() {
      console.log(getSelectedValue() + ' selected');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
form {display: inline}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<form id="randomId-839054763">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="5">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="6">
</form>
<button>Log value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

problem in your code: on change event not assign to radio button so undefined alert popup

here is solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
                alert($('input[name=option]:checked', '#form_56').val());

            });
        });
```